# Cannot scroll terminal on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I've installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 in a Samsung PC (NOT VM), but I cannot scroll up and down, and without a mouse I do not know how to do.

I've already tested <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>ArrowUup</kbd> but nothing. I cannot find anything around.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing this in a console (not in a GUI Terminal window), then it's "normal". Since kernel version 5.9, support for the scrollback buffer has been removed. See

- [fbcon: remove soft scrollback code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489)
- [vgacon: remove software scrollback support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=973c096f6a85e5b5f2a295126ba6928d9a6afd45)

In a console, you can use `less` or `screen` instead.

If it's just a single command which outputs more than a screen and you want to see it all, pipe the output through `less` :

```
your_command | less
```

If it's for interactive use or several commands, start a new `screen` session (eg. `screen -RD`), and use that to enter your commands. To view what has scrolled out of the screen, use Ctrl-A Esc. Then you can use PageUp/PageDown. To exit that mode, use Esc.

To exit the screen session while keeping it running, use Ctrl-A D (Disconnect). You can then re-attach to that session with `screen -RD` (or `screen -r your.session.id` if you have multiple sessions in the background))

See `man screen` for all the details. Or inside a screen session, use Ctrl-A ? to view the available commands.

Comment: How it's supposed to use them? I need to change the code manually? Or can i renable the scrollback?

Comment: @Romans: see updated answer

Comment: OMG, what a vandalism of the kernel.